# new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() always going to fail

Tags: android, asynchronous

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();    
params.put("username", username);
params.put("password", password);
client.post("192.168.12.4/administration/include/login.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MySQL DB has been informed about Sync activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
            System.out.println("onFailure");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

If i have the code above what may cause it to go to `public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {}` instead of `public void onSuccess(String response) {}`

Where `192.168.12.4` is the IP of the computer where the localhost is running and where the project what contains `login.php` is located

Comment: localhost works only for particulate PC i guess. It want be abple to access on your device.

Comment: If it is local host then run in emulator.

Comment: What are the values of `statusCode`, `error` and `content`?

Comment: @KNeerajLal this is the out put in failure `I/System.out: onFailure
I/System.out: 0
I/System.out: java.net.MalformedURLException: No valid URI scheme was provided
I/System.out: null`  when i do `System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(statusCode);
                        System.out.println(error);
                        System.out.println(content);`

Comment: are testing in an emulator?

Comment: yes @user1506104 i am using emulator i also tried changing IP to `10.0.2.2/administration/include/login.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a developer machine (your PC where the emulator is running on) to emulator test, you must change your URL value to

```
http://10.0.2.2/administration/include/login.php
```

And don't forget to add this in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: this one helped go success. last question what does this mean `D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default`

Comment: This is something you can add to your manifest if you want to further configure your connection such as for Trusted certificates, which is the case for HTTPS connections. For your case, you can ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

Add a protocol like 'http`or 'https` to the `URL`.

Change your `URL` from,

```
192.168.12.4/administration/include/login.php
```

to

```
http://192.168.12.4/administration/include/login.php
```

Comment: i am checking it sir give me a minute it is running